# StimulReport Error with MVC (Access Denied or Null Value)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I have a stimulus report that runs locally without any problems, but I get the following error in IIS

Access to the path 'Stimulsoft' is denied.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Stimulsoft' is denied.

Source Error : **Line 6**

```
Line 4:  }
Line 5: 
Line 6:  @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(options: new StiMvcViewerOptions()
Line 7:  {
Line 8:      Actions =
```

Code in Controller :

```
public ActionResult report()
        {
            var report = new StiReport();
            report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/SalaryReport.mrt"));
            report.Compile();
```

Code in View :

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Print";
}

@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(options: new StiMvcViewerOptions()
{
    Actions =
    {
        GetReport = "report",
        ViewerEvent = "viewerEvent"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately no one answered my question and I finally found the solution myself, the reason for this error is in the version of the reporting software that needs to be changed.

add this code to web config :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
</appSettings>
```

Use StimulSoft Report 2015 or higher, version 2014 does not work properly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).